# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - API request

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to return different parts of an API response.

**My data:**

```
{
    "data": [
        "values": [
                     {
                         "value": {
                                      "X": 7544,
                                      "Y": 7532,
                                      "Z": 5298
                                   },
                          "end_time": "2016-11-01"
                      },
                      {
                          "value": {
                                      "X": 7566,
                                      "Y": 7579,
                                      "Z": 5304
                                    },
                           "end_time": "2016-11-02"
                       }
         ]
   ]
}
```

This is the response I get when I call 'data = json_object['data']':

```
[{'description': 'xxx', 'title': 'yyy', 'values': [{'end_time': '2016-12-01', 'value': {'v1': 187, 'v2': 4}}, {'end_time': '2016-12-02', 'value': {'v1': 177, 'v2': 6}}], 'name': 'name', 'id': '87654/', 'period': ‘day'}]
```

**My code:**

```
def myfunc():
    r = requests.get('URL...')
    json_object = r.json()
    data = json_object['data']
    end_time = data[0]['values'][0]['end_time']
    values = data[0]['values'][0]['value']
    return render_template('results.html', date = end_time, result = values)
```

Right now I got only first value and end_time. All attempts to return all end with this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Please help!

Comment: can you add stack trace.

Comment: I would decompose the expression, for instance: `data[0]['values'][0]['end_time']`. Try to print each data before accessing the deeper one.

Comment: This is an invalid json. Please paste a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are looking for is `end_time = data[0](['values'][0]['end_time'])` - right now it is looking for data[0]['values'], which gives an error as 'values' is a string.

Comment: This 'end_time = data[0](['values'][0]['end_time'])' still gives me the error:
'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your json

`values`is a key which holds value of type array. Assuming `values` is the parent element, you need

```
data["values"][0]['end_time']
```

Comment: Tried this too: end_time = data['values'][0]['end_time']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one element `values`, then you can do:

```
data[0]['values'][0]['end_time']
```

If you have many items in your data object, you may need to loop over it like this:

```
for item in data:
    end_time = item['values'][0]['end_time']
    # ...
```

Moreover, in `values`, you have more than one item, to read `end_time` of each item inside `values`, you can do:

```
for item in data:
    for value in item['values']
        end_time = value['end_time']
        # ...
```

Comment: This is what I am doing but I need to return each 'value' for each 'end_time'... Now I'm getting only the first one.

Comment: Take a look at my last edit, you need to have 2 for loops if you want to read all `end_time` attributes.

Comment: Yeah, I tried loops too. This - 
`    for item in data:
        for value in item['values']:
            end_time = value['end_time']
    return end_time`
returns only the last end_time

Comment: Because you need to do something else instead of my `# ...`

Comment: I do not know what you  want to do with that, that's why I just wrote `# ...`, if you just want to store them in some list for example, you can use `some_list.append(end_time)` instead of `# ...`. Do not forget to declare `some_list` outside `for` loops!

Comment: So instead of `# ...` write `print end_time`

Comment: That's what I did and it printed only the second date.

Comment: Please correct your data format, this `"data": ["values": [...]]` is not valid! you can not have something like `"values": [....` inside a list

Comment: Ok... I managed to store all dates in a list and print it. But that's not what I want. I need to render my template: `return render_template('results.html', date = end_time, result = values)`. No idea how to do that in a meaningful way so I have: date:xxx, value for this date:yyy etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got luck with iterating through the dict in that list with `value['value']` in the end. Thank you all for helping me!